# Let $X=U\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ and let $X_n = U+\mathbb{I}_{(0,n^{-1})}(U)$. Then does $X_n\stackrel{a.s}{\rightarrow}X$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables. Let $X$ be another random variable. Then, $X_n\stackrel{a.s}{\rightarrow}X $ if there exists $A\subset\Omega$ such that $P(A)=1$ and $ \lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)=X(\omega),\forall\omega\in A$

Let $X=U\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ and let $X_n = U+\mathbb{I}_{(0,n^{-1})}(U)$

Then $X_n$ does not converge almost surely to $X$ since, $$\forall\epsilon\in(0,1), \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}[U\in(0,n^{-1})]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-1}=\text{unbounded}$$

But, $\forall \omega $ such that $U(\omega)>0$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)$ and $\mathbb{P}(U>0)=1$, and so $X_n\stackrel{a.s}{\rightarrow}X$. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: reread the statement of borel-cantelli lemma

Comment: @Andrew, so is $a.s \iff \sum_n{P(|X_n - X|>\varepsilon)} < \infty \;,\ \forall \;\ \varepsilon >0$ wrong? is it only that RHS implies LHS? I just assumed LHS implies RHS because, all the terms of the rest of the series must vanish at infinity

Comment: yes, of course it's wrong